# Are these equivalent definitions of the Wasserstein-metric?

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces

Let $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ be two probability density functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. The [Wasserstein metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) is defined as
$$W_p(\rho_0,\rho_1)^p = \inf E(|X-Y|^p)$$ where the infimum is taken over all joint distributions of random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose marginals are $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ respectively.

I read a paper in which $W_p(\rho_1,\rho_2)$ was defined differently-

We say that a map $M: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ realizes a transfer of $\rho_0$ to $\rho_1$ if, for all bounded subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$\int_{x \in A} \rho_1(x)dx = \int_{M(x) \in A}\rho_0(x)dx$$
In particular, if $M$ is a smooth one-to-one map, the above just means 
$$\det(\nabla M(x))\rho_1(x) = \rho_0(x)$$
Using this, they defined the Wasserstein distance as 
$$W_p(\rho_0,\rho_1)^p = \inf_M \int|M(x)-x|^p\rho_0(x)dx$$
for all maps $M$ which transport $\rho_0$ to $\rho_1$.

My question is, why are the above definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second paper used Monge's formulation of the optimal transport problem, which seeks to minimize cost among all transfer **maps**: those maps that push $\rho_0$ to $\rho_1$. What makes this problem hard is that the set of transfer maps has no linear structure. Kantorovich proposed a relaxed version of the transport problems, in which the cost is minimized among all transfer **plans** $\mu$, i.e., the probability measures with marginals $\rho_0, \rho_1$. Any transfer map $M$ induces a transport plan $\mu$, namely the pushforward of $\rho_0$ via $x\mapsto (x,M(x))$ (which is supported on the graph of $M$). The converse is not true: Kantorovich allows  measures that are not supported on any graph.  Such measures can be through of as splitting the amount available at source at $x$ and sending parts of it to different destinations,  rather than a single point $M(x)$. The obvious advantage of Kantorovich's formulation is that the set of transfer plans is **convex**.

So, the distance defined via the Kantorovich problem never exceeds the distance defined via the Monge problem. It is a nontrivial result that for strictly convex costs such as $c(x,y)=|c-y|^p$, $p>1$, the optimal measure in the Kantorovich problem is actually supported on a graph and therefore solves the Monge problem as well. As a consequence, both definitions of the distance turn out to be equivalent. The best source for this material is the book *Topics in Optimal transportation* by Villani. (Not to be confused with his later book "Optimal transport" which puts the subject in a different, more geometric framework).

Frankly, I don't know why anyone would use the Monge formulation to define a **metric**, since a metric is supposed to be symmetric. There's no symmetry between source and target in the Monge problem. The Kantorovich problem is obviously symmetric.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! I actually read up a bit about this question after posting it here (I posted it last year!). I found these notes extremely useful: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf

Comment: @VSJ Yes, I figured you'd find an answer by now, but it was too good a question to leave hanging. Someone may find it from search. Thanks for adding the link; it's a very accessible introduction to the topic.